# nMap scan ssl cipher list fail if argument -sV added

Tags: c, openssl, nmap

To All,

I am writing a service running HTTPS protocol that accept secure connection using Openssl.
After that, I tested SSL connection using nmap with the following command:

```
    nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 192.168.2.1
    
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
    Host is up (0.0029s latency).
    PORT    STATE SERVICE
    443/tcp open  https
    | ssl-enum-ciphers:
    |   TLSv1.2:
    |     ciphers:
    |       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256k1) - A
    |       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256k1) - A
    |     compressors:
    |       NULL
    |     cipher preference: client
    |_  least strength: A
```

However, if the the argument -sV is added, then it displays following

```
    nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -sV -p 443 192.168.2.1
    
    Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-05-25 09:15 CST
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
    Host is up (0.0030s latency).
    PORT    STATE SERVICE    VERSION
    443/tcp open  ssl/https?
    
    Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 12.79 seconds
```

the -sV is used to probe service/version info, I am wondering is it because I am using ECHDE only?

Anyway, here's how I setup my SSL connection (Remove error checking for easy reading).

```
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    CTX = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_server_method());
    SL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384");
    SSL_CTX_ctrl((CTX),SSL_CTRL_SET_ECDH_AUTO,1,NULL);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(CTX, pem, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(CTX, pem, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(CTX, chain);
```

I am suspecting the ciphers ECDHE, because if I use Cipher list "AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384", everything seems to work fine.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.